something is broken while trying to install anything using apt install. Can't install any nvidia driver or Nodejs, can't apt purge
I found this error today while trying to install a nvidia driver for my clean ubuntu install.
sudo ubuntu-drivers install fails:
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nvidia-compute-utils-545 nvidia-firmware-545-545.29.06
  nvidia-kernel-common-545 nvidia-kernel-source-545 nvidia-prime
  nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-545
Recommended packages:
  libnvidia-compute-545:i386 libnvidia-decode-545:i386
  libnvidia-encode-545:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-545:i386 libnvidia-gl-545:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-compute-utils-545 nvidia-dkms-545 nvidia-driver-545
  nvidia-firmware-545-545.29.06 nvidia-kernel-common-545
  nvidia-kernel-source-545 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-545
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/86.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 145 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-compute-utils-545.
(Reading database ... 153380 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-nvidia-compute-utils-545_545.29.06-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-compute-utils-545 (545.29.06-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-kernel-source-545.
Preparing to unpack .../1-nvidia-kernel-source-545_545.29.06-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-kernel-source-545 (545.29.06-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-firmware-545-545.29.06.
Preparing to unpack .../2-nvidia-firmware-545-545.29.06_545.29.06-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-firmware-545-545.29.06 (545.29.06-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-kernel-common-545.
Preparing to unpack .../3-nvidia-kernel-common-545_545.29.06-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-kernel-common-545 (545.29.06-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-dkms-545.
Preparing to unpack .../4-nvidia-dkms-545_545.29.06-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-dkms-545 (545.29.06-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-utils-545.
Preparing to unpack .../5-nvidia-utils-545_545.29.06-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-utils-545 (545.29.06-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-driver-545.
Preparing to unpack .../6-nvidia-driver-545_545.29.06-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-driver-545 (545.29.06-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-prime.
Preparing to unpack .../7-nvidia-prime_0.8.17.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-prime (0.8.17.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-settings.
Preparing to unpack .../8-nvidia-settings_510.47.03-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-settings (510.47.03-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up nvidia-firmware-545-545.29.06 (545.29.06-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-prime (0.8.17.2) ...
Setting up nvidia-kernel-source-545 (545.29.06-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-utils-545 (545.29.06-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-compute-utils-545 (545.29.06-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.1) ...
info: The home dir /nonexistent you specified can't be accessed: No such file or directory

info: Selecting UID from range 100 to 999 ...

info: Selecting GID from range 100 to 999 ...
info: Adding system user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 122) ...
info: Adding new group `nvidia-persistenced' (GID 124) ...
info: Adding new user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 122) with group `nvidia-persistenced' ...
info: Not creating `/nonexistent'.
Setting up nvidia-settings (510.47.03-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up nvidia-kernel-common-545 (545.29.06-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service.wants/nvidia-hibernate.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-hibernate.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/systemd-suspend.service.wants/nvidia-resume.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-resume.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service.wants/nvidia-resume.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-resume.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/systemd-suspend.service.wants/nvidia-suspend.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-suspend.service.
Setting up nvidia-dkms-545 (545.29.06-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Loading new nvidia-545.29.06 DKMS files...
Building for 6.8.0-31-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 6.8.0-31-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-kernel-source-545.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-31-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/545.29.06/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-545 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-545 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-545:
 nvidia-driver-545 depends on nvidia-dkms-545 (<= 545.29.06-1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-545 is not configured yet.
 nvidia-driver-545 depends on nvidia-dkms-545 (>= 545.29.06); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-545 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-545 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142ubuntu25.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-31-generic
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1.1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.39-0ubuntu8.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.12.0-4build2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.27-2build1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-545
 nvidia-driver-545
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

sudo apt purge fails:
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Removing old nvidia-545.29.06 DKMS files...
Deleting module nvidia-545.29.06 completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new nvidia-545.29.06 DKMS files...
Building for 6.8.0-31-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 6.8.0-31-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-kernel-s
ource-545.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-31-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/545.29.06/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-545 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-545 package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-545:
 nvidia-driver-545 depends on nvidia-dkms-545 (<= 545.29.06-1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-545 is not configured yet.
 nvidia-driver-545 depends on nvidia-dkms-545 (>= 545.29.06); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-545 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-545 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
                          Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142ubuntu25
.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-31-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-545
 nvidia-driver-545
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

sudo apt install nodejs fails:
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Removing old nvidia-545.29.06 DKMS files...
Deleting module nvidia-545.29.06 completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new nvidia-545.29.06 DKMS files...
Building for 6.8.0-31-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 6.8.0-31-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-kernel-s
ource-545.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-31-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/545.29.06/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-545 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-545 package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 10
Setting up node-cjs-module-lexer (1.2.3+dfsg-1) ...
Setting up nodejs-doc (18.19.1+dfsg-6ubuntu5) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-545:
 nvidia-driver-545 depends on nvidia-dkms-545 (<= 545.29.06-1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-545 is not configured yet.
 nvidia-driver-545 depends on nvidia-dkms-545 (>= 545.29.06); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-545 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-545 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up node-xtend (4.0.2-3) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
                          Setting up node-busboy (1.6.0+~cs2.6.0-2) ...
Setting up node-undici (5.26.3+dfsg1+~cs23.10.12-2) ...
Setting up node-acorn (8.8.1+ds+~cs25.17.7-2) ...
Setting up libnode109:amd64 (18.19.1+dfsg-6ubuntu5) ...
Setting up nodejs (18.19.1+dfsg-6ubuntu5) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/nodejs to provide /usr/bin/js (js) in auto m
ode
Processing triggers for man-db (2.12.0-4build2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.39-0ubuntu8.2) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142ubuntu25.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-31-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-545
 nvidia-driver-545
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

In all cases I have truncated the error message
Maybe the problem is something I did, or something an Nvidia installer did, during my attempts to install a functioning Nvidia driver + CUDA + cuDNN install.
Everything I do with apt hangs around 20% here:
Deleting module nvidia-545.29.06 completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new nvidia-545.29.06 DKMS files...
Building for 6.8.0-31-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 6.8.0-31-generic

Progress: [ 20%] [################################.....

edit: if i switch to "Using X.Org" in Software & Updates => Additional Drivers, which is the default open source driver, i can purge & autoremove. But, I still can't install a Nvidia driver that works with CUDA like I want to. If I try the original sudo ubuntu-drivers install cmd again, it'll  re-break stuff.
edit2: I tried the suggestion of trying different drivers. I found via another post that the right way to do this is sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535-open. So I tried nvidia-driver-535-open, nvidia-driver-470, both of which nvidia-smi said:
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver i installed and running.

sudo apt install nvidia-driver-545 gave me
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Loading new nvidia-545.29.06 DKMS files...
Building for 6.8.0-31-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 6.8.0-31-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-kernel-s
ource-545.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-31-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/545.29.06/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-545 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-545 package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-545:
 nvidia-driver-545 depends on nvidia-dkms-545 (<= 545.29.06-1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-545 is not configured yet.
 nvidia-driver-545 depends on nvidia-dkms-545 (>= 545.29.06); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-545 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-545 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
                          Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.39-0ubuntu8.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.12.0-4build2) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142ubuntu25.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-31-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-545
 nvidia-driver-545
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

so I tried to install nvidia-dkms-545 but it gave another error I will paste a bit of:
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-kernel-s
ource-545.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-31-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/545.29.06/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-545 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-545 package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 10
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142ubuntu25.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-31-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-545
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Summary: Tried installing various nvidia drivers. Some looked like they installed but nvidia-smi said it "couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver" and python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))" continued to output:
CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected
[]


The 6.8 kernel takes the gcc-13 compler.  Is that installed? Ubuntu 24.04 doesn't have any gcc installed by default anymore, so a sudo apt install gcc should work to get gcc-13 and dependencies.

From experience: not all versions of the nvidia drivers work for a specific ubuntu version. My advice is; Try them one at a time.

@ubfan1 Writing to confirm that gcc 13.2.0 was installed while I was trying this.

so, I guess the apt install problem is fixed now, so  long as I switch to "Using X.Org" in Software & Updates => Additional Drivers, which is the default open source driver, i can purge & autoremove the nvidia stuff. Nvidia still won't work though
edit: I think this post here has the functioning solution:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/error-installing-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu/231193/6
Well my problem is now fixed…for anyone if it helps
I tried to unistall and reinstall again a different version of nvidia …removed nvidia 515 and replaced it with 535 version.

what I used were these commands
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libnvidia-common-515 libnvidia-gl-515 nvidia-driver-515

I am not sure what was the problem but it is working now when I check with
nvidia-smi or nvcc --version
both return the expected output of nvidia driver and cuda version

And Using torch is going well also

However I am unaware of the status of the nvidia-dkms-<version_number> package or whether this issue will appear again

so after running
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libnvidia-common-515 libnvidia-gl-515 nvidia-driver-515

and rebooting, not only does reboot get me to the desktop, but nvidia-smi shows the expected output.
